# How to change the color of a container once clicked on flutter, dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the color of only one container once it is clicked on.
Code:

```
bool ispressed = false;
    
ListView.builder(
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemCount: 7,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                                    return Smalcontainer(
                                      name: name[index],
                                      number: Number[index],
                                      color: ispressed
                                          ? Colors.white
                                          : Colors.grey[200],
                                          onTap: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          ispressed = true;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    );
                                  }),
```

I tried the above code but it changes the color of the whole row.

**Edit**
I tried @Thanawit's answer but I get the following error:

> type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'List' of 'function result'

Comment: What is Smalcontainer?

Comment: it is a container wrapped with a gesture detector

Answer (score 0):

your *ispressed* variable controls all of the containers, so you have to separate *ispressed* variable to control each of container

**change *ispressed* to List of bool and change the return code**

```
List<bool> ispressed;
```

**

```
 itemBuilder: (context, int index) {


 return Smalcontainer(
    name: name[index],
    number: Number[index],
    color: ispressed[index]
    ? Colors.white: Colors.grey[200],
    onTap: () {
        setState(() {
            ispressed[index] = true;
            });
    },
 )
```

},

Comment: I get the following error : `type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'List<bool>' of 'function result'`